# Why is this SML function returning a syntax error?

Tags: function, functional-programming, sml, smlnj, ml

```
fun first_answer(my_f:('a -> 'b option)) : 'a list -> 'b =
let
fun help(_a:'a list) : 'a =
(((List.map valOf)o(List.filter isSome)o(List.map my_f)) _a)
in
help
end;

Error: syntax error: replacing WILD with SEMICOLON
```

Something with that _a is messing it up..... The error is linked to the last usage of `_a`

I am not getting very far, and I've rearranged the logic many ways already. As you can see the first_answer returns takes a function and returns a function.  This is what I am doing here and I am following the types as far as I know. There is probably something simple that I am not seeing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple indeed: an identifier cannot start with an underscore. So `_a` is parsed as if you had written `_  a`, in accordance with the usual *maximal munch* rule for lexical syntax.

*Edit*: Extra tip: Your function does not have the type `'a list -> 'b`, because `help` returns a list of `'b`s, not a single value of type `'b`. Moreover, as written, it can be implemented more easily as

```
fun first_answer f xs = List.mapPartial f xs
```

or, in fact,

```
val first_answer = List.mapPartial
```